# Returning TRUE every time

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $Uploads = new Uploads($_FILES);
    $Uploads->UploadLocation = "../images/categories/";
    if($Uploads->isValidated()== TRUE){
    $Image = array("image" => $Uploads->upload());
    $_POST = array_merge($_POST,$Image);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $Category = new Categories();
    $Category->insertCategory("users", $_POST);
    }
    else {
        print_r($Uploads->isValidated());   
    }
}
?>
```

I have put  if statetment before `$Uploads->isValidated()` function so the rest of the code should only run once it returns true. Below is the functioin code.

```
public function isValidated(){
        if($this->containsError() && $this->isValidFile() && $this->isValidSize()){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->ValidationMessages;
        }
    }
```

I have checked if all the three methods return TRUE than my `isValidated()` method should return TRUE. the `$this->ValidationMessages` is an array of messages which is filled if any of the three validation method does not return TRUE.

Now i am deliberately not passing any file to this class to check if i am getting error messages but it is still running the rest of the code which seems that my `isValidated()`  method is returning TRUE which it should not.

Please note that my 3 validation methods are working perfect as i have checked all of them and that's why i am not posting them here. But if you need i can post the code.

I need help in figuring out why i am not getting validation messages.

Updated Part:

```
private function containsError(){
        //checking if file contains any error
        if(!empty($this->FileError)){
            $this->ValidationMessages[] = "Sorry, This file contains error";
        }
        else {
            return TRUE;
        }     
    }

   private function isValidFile() {
        // putting the allowed files in array
        $AllowedExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
        // matching with allowed file types
        if (in_array($this->FileExt, $AllowedExt)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->ValidationMessages[] = "This extension is not allowed";
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

private function isValidSize() {
    // setting the maximum size limit in bytes
    $AllowedSize = 1048576;
    // checking if the user file does not exceed the allowed size
    if (!$this->FileSize < $AllowedSize) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->ValidationMessages[] = "File should not be greater than 1MB";
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$Uploads->isValidated() === TRUE`

Comment: `if($this->containsError()` should be `if(!$this->containsError()` - It just makes more sense

Comment: Can't see what containsError is doing but it looks like you are saying "if there IS an error AND everything else is ok)... How can there be errors and everything ok? What does that function check and return?

Comment: wait i am updating my methods here

Comment: @Masadow I've updated my methods please have a look

Comment: @RameezShah In this case, `containsError` should be renamed in `doNotContainsError` or returning `false` and do write `if(!$this->containsError()`. It really makes more sense. Because when someone else reads your code, he won't understand and first think there is a mistake.

Comment: yeah i got your point.. i am gonna correct it...any idea whats wrong  going here?

Comment: @RameezShah raina77ow gave you the solution in the very first comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isValidated()` always returns a value that *evaluates to `true`* (i.e. not a pure boolean with a `true` value, but evaluated to `true` nevertheless). That is because it either returns `TRUE` or a (presumably) non-empty array of strings.

You have two choices here:

1. Either make `isValidated()` return `false` in the `else` case
2. Or change your `if` to `if($Uploads->isValidated()===TRUE)` (notice the triple `=`). That would check not only the value but also *the type of the value* returned by `isValidated()`. In other words, it will succeed only if the return value is *a boolean with a value of `true`* and not just any value that evaluates to `true`.

Comment: i've tried it earlier..let me do once again as i made some changes in class too.

Comment: @geogmagas thanks its worked fine but got one more problem here.. I print_r(messages) and its showing
Array ( [0] => Sorry, This file contains error [1] => Sorry, This file contains error ) Why it is showing it 2 times?

Comment: Because you call `$Uploads->isValidated()` twice -- once in the condition and once in the `else` clause.

Comment: Returning false within `isValidated()` would make more sense